# sp_BlitzCache and encrypted procedure

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzcache

I went on to run sp_BlitzCache in a production SQL Server 2014 server and I can see the procedures displayed, being reported as:

> "We couldn't find a plan for this query."

I have a feeling that this is due to the procs being encrypted.

Should we have our procedures not encrypted in order to get better information by sp_Blitz?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to tune the query, you need to be able to see the query, not to mention its plan.

Answer (score 4):

You should decrypt your procedures because it affects more than sp_BlitzCache. Query Store, Extended Events, DMVs, etc.

It doesn't provide much security anyway. There are free tools that can decrypt the procedures.